# Check validation from user in C programming

Tags: c

This is a snippet of my code. I'm confused why is digit can't function. It should if we input character/alphabet. The line is digit print "Please enter in numeric " but it doesn't print it. I need your opinion about this.

This my code:

```c
printf("\nenter the amount of food to be purchased  : ");
scanf("%d", &b);
printf("\n");
            
if (b >= 0) {
 for (a=1; a<=b; a++){
   printf("the price of food of- %d \t : ",a);
   scanf("%d", &c);
   printf("\n");
                
   if (isdigit(c)) {
     printf("Please enter in numeric !!\n");
     while ((getchar()) != '\n'); 
     system("PAUSE");
     goto cashier;
   }
   printf("the amount ordered \t : ");
   scanf("%d", &d);
   printf("\n");
                
   if (isdigit(d)) {
     printf("Please enter in numeric !!\n");
     while ((getchar()) != '\n'); 
     system("PAUSE");
     goto cashier;
   }
```

Comment: You do not show definition of `c` ... but having `scanf("%d", &c);` we can assume it is `int` ... and `isdigit(c)` expects a character code, not a number *per se* (`isdigit('4')` is ok, `isdigit(52)` is not ok (although they are the same in ASCII based computers))

Comment: c is an integer, i declared before

Comment: but why if i input alphabet is not print Please enter in numeric? @pmg

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: The beginning of any input validation in C starts with checking what [`scanf` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%d",  &c);`. Reads an integer to c. When you call `isdigit(c)`, you are not checking whether the input string is a number, you are checking whether the number inputted corresponds to an ascii character that represents a digit. This is not the intended behavior. What you want is this:

```
  while (scanf("%d", &c) != 1) // Repeatedly get input until scanf reads 1 integer.
  {
    while (getchar()!='\n'); // Clear stdin.
    puts("Please enter a number!");
  }
// The resulting number is now stored in c.
```

This will try to read a number (not a string) into c. If the user does not enter 1 number, `scanf()` will not return 1 and the loop will try again. make sure that c is declared as an `int` and not a `char`, else numbers above 128 will overflow.

Comment: but we must enter an integer again after that statement execute. can it not input an integer again ?

Comment: @ryand I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to say here. Could you rephrase?

Comment: after this statement:while (scanf("%d", &c) != 1) // Repeatedly get input until scanf reads 1 integer.
  {
    while (getchar()!='\n'); // Clear stdin.
    puts("Please enter a number!");
  }                                                                                                                                if i input integer the program will continue to next statement:                                                          
        printf("the amount ordered \t : ");
            scanf("%d", &d); but before that we must input an integer again. can it not happen to input again

Comment: Oh, you want to enter two numbers? Just put my code twice, using a different variable instead of &c the second time. Then you have two integers stored in two variables.